# why is there a high variance in ping to wifi router with full signal?

Tags: networking, router, ping, wifi-configuration

I have a wifi router in the same room as my macbook air laptop. Sometimes my network gets very bad , I dont know why I am not able to consistently ping my router just 2meters away

I changed the router , but that did not help. How do I debug this

This is the ping output at bad times

```
[ram@NL672 ~]$ ping 192.168.0.1 -c 10
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=30 time=9.786 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=30 time=7062.953 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=30 time=6205.862 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=30 time=5470.707 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=30 time=4504.167 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=30 time=3885.971 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=30 time=2885.395 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=30 time=1915.055 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=30 time=941.990 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=30 time=942.002 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=30 time=466.723 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, +1 duplicates, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 9.786/3117.328/7062.953/2351.120 ms
```

Comment: Are you using a 2G or 5G channel, is there any physical obstacle between you and the router (e.g. a wall). Check your wifi for interfering networks (there are apps on a phone that can show that). Do you have the same issue if you are using a LAN cable (helps to isolate if this is WiFi issue or a router issue). Do you have the same issue when pining external internet hosts?

Comment: This is almost certainly a configuration issue with both the router and the client wifi card settings. **Router:** WiFi radios need to be assigned actual DFS channels, not left on Auto _(2.4GHz channels: `1`, `6`, or `11`; 5GHz channels (80MHz): highest DFS channel available - in the US, `157` works best || (160MHz): likely channels `50` or `114`)_. You'll also want to disable legacy channel support for `b` and `g` on both the router and the client. **Client:** WiFi card settings should be customized, however these vary by OS and card.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ The following two links will provide more information about the above: [Configuring Wi-Fi Channels And Channel Widths To Fix Slow Speeds And Disconnects](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/wi-fi-channels-and-channel-widths-to-fix-low-speeds-and-disconnects/) and [this](https://www.ekahau.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Detailed-5-GHz-Channel-Allocations.jpg) band and channel width graphic.

Comment: Ping will increase massively if either the upstream or downstream is clogged. Are you running other network intensive programs in the background, such as torrenting, updates, streaming, etc?

Comment: @LPChip By hundreds to thousands of ms to the router's internal IP? I would understand how that could occur to a WAN side ping, but AFAIK internal LAN-side traffic shouldn't be affected by heavy WAN-side throughput _(or am I thinking about this in the wrong way)_?

Comment: You are thinking about it the wrong way... wifi uses CSMA/CA on the shared media, (channel in use) so its not just your router and clients on the media, its every device/ap/ router on that channel. heavy congestion on a channel will most certainly cause issues like this, even disconnects if the interfering signals are strong enough.